# Clone Windows 3.11 Hard Drive

Tags: windows, clone

I have a really old production machine that runs on windows 3.11.  Lately it has been locking up and we are getting the dreaded BSOD.  I am wanting to clone the hard drive.  That is if I can find a compatible one.

**I plan to**:

- Install Windows 3.11 on the new drive.
- Then copy the entire old hard drive over to the new hard drive.

Will this produce a hard drive that I can just plug in and have it work once the old drive fails?

Comment: Probably not due to unique IDs. Have you considered the option of migrating that machine to a virtual guest?

Comment: No, that wouldn't be possible for this situation.  The machine uses a lot of old custom expansion cards in order to communicate with the machine.  Also, the motherboard is custom as well.  I wouldn't be able to plug a newer PC into it.

Comment: Unless the software uses the HDD's serial to create a unique id, which only you can tell us if thats the case, your plan sounds solid enough.

Comment: Wouldn't installing a fresh copy of 3.11 take care of the unique ID?

Comment: What makes you think the BSOD would go away with a new hard drive? That is, what makes you think the hard drive itself is responsible for the BSOD? It's possible, certainly, but unlikely.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton, I don't think it is the hard drive that is causing the BSOD.  But, in case the HD is experiencing issues, I want have a good working backup drive.  Down time is critical with production machines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Really you just need to format and install DOS on the new drive and then use `xcopy /s /e` to copy everything to the new drive.

Remember that Windows 3.11 is not an operating system.  It was simply an application installed on top of DOS.  Old DOS+Windows 3.x systems were trivial to clone.  You just copied the files to another drive and then made sure you prepared the new drive to boot.  Which can be as simple as running `sys driveletter:` or passing the `/b` option to format when you created the filesystem.

About the only time you ever ran into issues was with early DRM software that did weird things like bypassing the OS and writing secret bits directly to the drive in unusual locations.